# Chrome for Android tab group bar goes missing occasionally

Tags: bug, chat, scrolling, mobile-chrome

Google have recently introduced tab groups in Google Android, and [are experimenting with them](https://9to5google.com/2021/09/03/chrome-tab-groups-android/)

However, I've noticed a bug they cause in stackexchange chat that may be fixable?

Occasionally the tab group bar at the bottom vanishes, my guess is that whatever scroll event triggers it to appear is swallowed/prevented by chat?

Here is an animated example of the behaviour:

[image: initially scrolling does not cause the tab group bar to appear, but clicking the view tab button shows the page was in a group]

Not sure if this is high priority (easy work around + potential for the feature to change in the future) but it seemed worth flagging up so it can at least be noted as a known bug.

I'm using Chrome 96 on Android 10.

Comment: I haven't checked to see if this has been resolved by Google in Chrome, but this is *entirely* a bug in Chrome, not SE chat. This is a browser feature which the page should be unable to affect. It shouldn't be incumbent on SE, or any site, to change their site in order to not affect a basic part of the browser's functionality.

Comment: @Makyen yes and no. For instance if there's something deprecated by Chrome that the site relied on then it should be updated by the site not too use that.

Comment: Yes, but that's a significantly different issue than the site being *able to* interfere with the operation of the browser. The browser's operation should be impervious to *anything* that the site can do. The site should, of course, be able to change how the site is displayed, but it shouldn't be able to cause the failure of browser functionality outside of the page.

Comment: As someone who has used tab groups for the past couple of years, I doubt there is anything we can do to fix this. It consistently disappears when you start to scroll down, but is very inconsistent on reappearing when scrolling up. I was glad they turned off the feature by default because it was so sporadic and frustrating to use across *many* sites. It seems to only work consistently on very basic sites that don't put scrollbars on anything other than the body element.